# Can private beta meta rep earned contribute towards parent profiles?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, private-beta

I don't mean the rep has to always add to the parent site, but during the private beta as a bit of a reward for helping out getting things going, up to the daily rep-cap.

Yes, I'm being whiny since I'm helping in a private beta. It doesn't have to be retroactive, but it could be going forward to help others.

Comment: Your reward for helping in a private beta is the beta succeeds and the site you like launches :). I could see maybe having a badge for getting so many upvotes on meta during the length of the beta, but altering how rep works for a single week is kind of weird

Comment: hahahahah, very funny @Michael ;)

Answer (score 3):

Drip-feeding rep from the meta sends the wrong idea.

Spend less time chewing the fat about the site and oil up to get down and dirty with the questions and answers that are to serve as the repository of all that is unholy and cooked.

Post and focus primarily on where it matters, where it's most visible to the drive-by readers and wayward eyeballs.

The metas are there to help you help yourselves in carving it up in guiding the light.

At the end of the private beta phase, your reward is the satisfaction that you were among the first to help push through another potential Stack Exchange site only forever ago sitting in the bowels of Area 51.

Comment: Trust me I see the logic presented here. I still stand by my request, but I don't anticipate seeing it happen.

Comment: Were you in the middle of reading a medical textbook when you wrote this?

Comment: @Aarobot  I think he was in the middle of reading Jack the Ripper ;)